# Can Android automatically pick the best location provider?

Tags: android

is there an option , where we can let Android Pick the best Provider.  In iOS, there is something  called best or bestForNavigation Option.

I know we can specify a criteria and pick the provider before requesting location Updates like below:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
String providerName = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

But other than setting a Criteria, is there way in which , the Android OS automatically picks the best provider. Basically i am trying to find an option in Android that is similar to the one available today on Apple IOS (like the best or bestForNavigation).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty `Criteria` object (`new Criteria()`). It is set up, by default, for the widest range of compliant location providers.

Comment: But does it choose the best when no criteria is set. On what basis is that decision made if the criteria object has no configuration parameters set?

Comment: @user2052129: The decision-making algorithm is not documented, last I checked, and as such should not be relied upon.

Comment: Yeah that's true, when i left the Criteria Object blank, it just picked WIFI/Cell Data as default, while GPS is better provider as far as accuracy is concerned.

Comment: @user2052129: Well, by default, `Criteria` assumes that accuracy is not especially important (`NO_REQUIREMENT`). You can specify that you want a certain level of accuracy, in which case GPS may wind up being the choice.